# Дано массив, вывести все индекы элементов которые множественный на 3

Tags: javascript

```
let x = [10,3,6,9,15,30]
```

пробовал так но не работает, а можно ли без фильтра?

```
let x = [10,3,6,9,15,30].filter((index) => (index*3)/3==3)
```

а можно получить сумма индексов?

Comment: я есть немного плохо понимать по-русски, перефразировать может быть есть вой вопрос плиз чуть

Comment: @Zhihar "три клох смен"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//let x = [10,3,6,9,15,30]
// пробовал так, работает
let indexes = [10,3,6,9,15,30].reduce((r, el, i) => { 
  if (!(el % 3)) r.push(i);
  return r;
}, []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(indexes));

let sumOfIndexes = indexes.reduce((r, el) => r + el);
console.log(sumOfIndexes);

// - а можно ли без фильтра?
// - А зачем?
```

Comment: ответ за принятый могу принять через 10 мин)

Comment: а можно получить сумма индексов?

Comment: @Мнебезсахара можно